# Disabled attribute not working in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an email field in an angular reactive form, that i want to be disabled if the form is in edit mode (as oppose to add mode). I am using

```
disabled: typeof user.user_id === 'string'
```

If i set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `modelToForm` method below and paste `typeof user.user_id === 'string'` into the console, it returns true, so it looks like it should be working but the field in the form is not disabled. If i change it to be 'disabled: true', the field IS disabled. Has anyone come across this?

```js
    public modelToForm(user: UserModel): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            firstName: [user.first_name, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(UserFormHelper.maxLengthName),
                UserFormHelper.validateWhitespace
            ]],
            email: [{value: user.email, disabled: typeof user.user_id === 'string'}, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(UserFormHelper.maxLengthEmail),
                Validators.pattern(UserFormHelper.emailPattern)
            ]],
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `typeof user.user_id === 'string'` is the condition you want at that time?

Comment: It should just work with - 'disabled: user.user_id', but using typeof user.user_id === 'string' should also work. And the condition seems to be true whenever i set a breakpoint at the start of the method and hit Edit (its false whenever i hit Add)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it! Setting disabled on form init is static? You'd need to manually change it when your condition changes?

```
control.disable()
control.enable()
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i got it working, i removed it from the reactive form and put it in the html - [attr.disabled]="user.user_id". Weird but as it used to work when i had it in the reactive form